# Loss decreases but model do not coverage

Tags: tensorflow, recommendation-engine

I try to implement a simply ctr prediction model using tensorflow. However, the training loss decreases but accuracy remains the same. (Actually it is exactly equal to the rate of positive or negative samples, seems that the model predicts 0 or 1 to all the samples). What should I do to solve this problem?

```py
def parse_exmp(serial_exmp):
    click = fc.numeric_column("click", dtype=tf.float32)
    fea_columns = [click]
    fea_columns += my_feature_columns
    feature_spec=tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(fea_columns)
    feats = tf.parse_single_example(serial_exmp, features=feature_spec)
    click = feats.pop('click')
    return feats, {'ctr': tf.to_float(click)}


def train_input_fn(filenames, batch_size, shuffle_buffer_size):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_exmp, num_parallel_calls=5)
    dataset = dataset.repeat().batch(batch_size).prefetch(1000)
    return dataset


def eval_input_fn(filename, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_exmp, num_parallel_calls=5)
    # Shuffle, repeat, and batch the examples.
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    # Return the read end of the pipeline.
    return dataset


def build_model(features, mode, params):
    net = fc.input_layer(features, params['feature_columns'])
    # Build the hidden layers, sized according to the 'hidden_units' param.

    for units in params['hidden_units']:
    net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=units, kernel_regularizer=None, 
                              bias_regularizer=None, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    if 'dropout_rate' in params and params['dropout_rate'] > 0.0:
        net = tf.layers.dropout(net, params['dropout_rate'], training=(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN))

    # Compute logits
    logits = tf.layers.dense(net, 1, activation=None)
    return logits

def my_model(features, labels, mode, params):
    ctr_logits = build_model(features, mode, params)
    ctr_predictions = tf.sigmoid(ctr_logits, name="CTR")

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        predictions = ctr_predictions
        export_outputs = {
            'prediction': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(predictions)
        }
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions, export_outputs=export_outputs)

    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels['ctr'], logits=ctr_logits), name="loss")

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=params['learning_rate'])
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

    ctr_accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels['ctr'], predictions=tf.to_float(tf.greater_equal(ctr_predictions, 0.5)))
    ctr_auc = tf.metrics.auc(labels['ctr'], ctr_predictions)

    metrics = {'ctr_accuracy': ctr_accuracy, 'ctr_auc': ctr_auc}
    tf.summary.scalar('ctr_accuracy', ctr_accuracy[1])
    tf.summary.scalar('ctr_auc', ctr_auc[1])

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)


create_feature_columns()
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=my_model,
    params={
            'feature_columns': my_feature_columns,
            'hidden_units': hidden_units.split(','),
            'learning_rate': learning_rate,
            'dropout_rate': dropout_rate
    },
    config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=model_dir, save_checkpoints_steps=save_checkpoints_steps)
)
batch_size = batch_size


train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(train_files, batch_size, shuffle_buffer_size),
    max_steps=train_steps
)
input_fn_for_eval = lambda: eval_input_fn(eval_files, batch_size)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=input_fn_for_eval, throttle_secs = 60, steps=None)
```

Here's the log:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
INFO:tensorflow:Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after 60 secs (eval_spec.throttle_secs) or training is finished.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into ./model_dir/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 8575.396, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 45 into ./model_dir/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 92.291855.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2019-06-10-07:05:03
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./model_dir/model.ckpt-45
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2019-06-10-07:05:17
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 45: ctr_accuracy = 0.436, ctr_auc = 0.5, global_step = 45, loss = 6467.209
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./model_dir/model.ckpt-45
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 46 into ./model_dir/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1430.6135, step = 46
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 87 into ./model_dir/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 469.1917.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2019-06-10-07:06:44
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./model_dir/model.ckpt-87
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2019-06-10-07:06:58
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 87: ctr_accuracy = 0.436, ctr_auc = 0.5, global_step = 87, loss = 3759.593
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./model_dir/model.ckpt-87
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 88 into ./model_dir/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 938.0892, step = 88
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 131 into ./model_dir/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 3.707542e-12.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2019-06-10-07:08:26
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./model_dir/model.ckpt-131
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2019-06-10-07:08:39
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 131: ctr_accuracy = 0.436, ctr_auc = 0.5, global_step = 131, loss = 2633.0947
```